# What is the correct structure for MVC + API + Authentication server project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, rest, api, token

I have an MVC project that sends/receive data to/from a web API.
In my MVC project, users can log in to access certain pages.

I would like to implement an "authentication service" with tokens to acces my web API for 2 reasons :
1) To secure my web aPI
2) To access the id of the user that is logged in on my MVC app

I have read following statement :

> The basic flow of things here is that your users will authenticate using OpenID Connect on your MVC site, after which they can get an access token to authorize access to the Web API using OAuth.

My question is :

I already have a project for my MVC app, a project for my web API. Do I need a third project for the token service?
If not, in which project do I implement it?

If anyone has an example or tutorial that would be great too.